# Jupyter Lab on AWS EC2: Memory issues when accessed by multiple browsers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I would like to know why the Jupyter Lab server crashes when accessed by multiple browsers (Chrome and Firefox).

To provide more details, I accessed the server on AWS EC2 (instance: t3.xlarge, OS: Ubuntu 20.04) using the command "jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0" from Chrome and ran the notebook. At this point, about half of the instance's memory was in use. Subsequently, when I accessed the same server with Firefox and displayed the notebook, more memory was occupied despite nothing being executed, leading to the server crashing due to lack of memory.

The server can be accessed via HTTPS communication, and the certificate is self-signed. After running the command "sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888" to allow access with port 443, I started Jupyter Lab with "nohup jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0". I also added a setting to jupyter_lab_config that requires a password when accessing Jupyter Lab.

The strange thing is, this phenomenon doesn't occur with other EC2 instances (I started multiple servers at once from a template), but only some instances exhibit the aforementioned memory-hogging behavior. What could be causing this?